# /usr/libexec/java_home command

Tags: macos, java-home

I am a native windows user and have never used linux/unix or any other operating system other then windows. Recently i have switched to Mac.
I installed java 8 into my mac machine. I somehow setup my JAVA_HOME variable as well. I had to struggle to find out where it is stored. After doing research on internet, i used the following command on my terminal to find out where my java is installed and correct path was provided.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

I am looking forward to know, what does this command mean?

Comment: It's a way of allowing you to access different versions of java in a unified manner through the command line. Try running it with `/usr/libexec/java_home -h` to see what kinds of options you can use for it.

Comment: petesh, i ran this command, is it a quick way to find different informations about JRE's present in MAC? It won't be to run them. Am i assuming correct?

Comment: It will list JREs that have been installed into system locations (`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`). It can run commands from the installed JREs as well, e.g. if I installed a 1.6 JVM, then I could invoke the 1.6 JRE with `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 --exec java`. It's [documented on the OSX developer tools manual pages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window. Type

```
man java_home
```

You will get:

> java_home(1)                                             java_home(1)
>
> NAME
>          java_home - return a value for $JAVA_HOME
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          /usr/libexec/java_home [options]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The java_home command returns a path suitable for setting the JAVA_HOME
>          environment variable.  It determines this path from the user's  enabled
>          and  preferred  JVMs  in  the Java Preferences application.  Additional
>          constraints may be provided to filter the list of JVMs  available.   By
>          default,  if  no  constraints  match  the  available  list of JVMs, the
>          default order is used.  The path is printed to standard output.